# How to do a bottom border like in finder?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I am trying to add a border att tha bottom of my textrured window with a sidebar. I would like to look exactly like in finder:

[alt text http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/finder-border.png](http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/finder-border.png)

for now it looks like that:

[alt text http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/twittia-border.png](http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/twittia-border.png)

And I can't find anything in Interface Builder how I can add this border.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You add that with NSWindow's setContentBorderThickness:forEdge:, passing NSMinYEdge for the edge. Note that this will only work if the window is *not* textured.

Comment: It doesn't help, I added it to the awakeFromNib method but I don't see any change.

Comment: Now I understand, the window should not be textured. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I forgot about that; I ran into the same problem the first time I tried to use that method! I've added that to the answer, so hopefully others won't have to struggle with it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **Bottom Bars** in [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/).